# How to create collapsible submenu items using Sidr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, menu, sidr

I'm using the Sidr in Wordpress to creata a mobile navigation and I'm trying to make collapsible submenus on click but failed.
Here's my code but doesn't work.

```
$(function(){
    $('.sidr-class-menu-item-has-children').each(function(){ // Each menu item with children
        $(this).on('click',function(){ // ...When clicked
            $(this).find('.sidr-class-sub-menu').show(); // Show sub menu
        });
    });
});
```

Any tips or help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add code as same:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidr-class-menu-item-has-children').each(function(){ // Each menu item with children
        $(this).on('click',function(){ // ...When clicked
            $(this).find('.sidr-class-sub-menu').show(); // Show sub menu
       });
    });
});
```

If no work, you can change $ to jQuery